# getting values from nested lists in groovy

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a 3 level nested list in groovy like this

```
rList = [[[12, name1],[22,name2],[49,name3]],[[33, name5],[22,name6],[21, name7]]]
```

how can I iterate it to get the name values from the 1st sublist
so I want like `rsublist = [name1, name2, name3]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rList = [[[12, 'name1'], [22, 'name2'], [49, 'name3']], [[33, 'name5'], [22, 'name6'], [21, 'name7']]]
names = rList[0]*.getAt(1)
assert names == ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

First, `rList[0]` gives you the first sub-list, which is `[[12, name1], [22, name2], [49, name3]]`. Then, the [spread operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator), `*.`, is used to apply the same method, `getAt(1)`, to every element of that list, which will return a list with every second element of the sub-lists, which are the values you were looking for :)

You can also use `rList[0].collect { it[1] }` which is equivalent and might be more familiar if you are not used to the spread operator.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [@epidemian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966219/462015), here's a more readable version:

```
rList.first()*.last()
```

Comment: +1 =D. Off-topic: the syntax highlighter on StackOverflow is really weird. Why would the `last` method call have a different color than `first`? I think it only recognizes a couple of "general" keywords and syntax forms (like comments and string literals, which are quite similar between different languages) I wish it were something more powerful, maybe like GitHub's language recognition and syntax highlighter.